# What are the gaming references in these book titles in Doom: Eternal?

Tags: doom-eternal

I saw this screenshot of a bookcase from the upcoming DOOM Eternal being passed around on a Discord I frequent recently (numbers added by me):

[image: A bookshelf stacked with many books.]

> 1. *My Buddy Superfly*
> 2. *Why I'm so Great Pt. II* by Dork Norkem
> 3. *Devilish Daggers*
> 4. *LIANDRI - A Brief History of Interplanetary Industry*
> 5. *Von Braun - Onboard AI System Technical Manual*
> 6. *Mesa Science Monthly: Predicting Unforeseen Consequences*
> 7. *U-NAT-CO Training Manual: Bomb Defusal*
> 8. *The Spear of Destiny: A Post-War Deconstruction*
> 9. *Living With Rage - and Other Common Emotions in the Apocalyptic Wasteland*
> 10. *The Strogg: A Transdimensional Field Study*
> 11. *RET-CONNED: The Life and Times of Flynn Taggart*
> 12. *From Nopefish to Dopefish: The Dope Tale*
> 13. *Tei Tenga - Offworld Travel Guide*
> 14. *Cooking from Hell's Kitchen - They Flesh Consumed*
> 15. *2 Prey or Not 2 Prey*
> 16. *Vault Dweller's Survival Guide - Preparing Yourself and Your Loved Ones For the Inevitable Nuclear Apocalypse*
> 17. *Nuka Cola - A History from the Atomic Age of Flavor*

Clearly, each book is a shout-out to another video game - I can recognize several of the references, but eight that I'm not certain about and it's left me curious what video games the books I don't recognize are referencing.

So far I have:

1. ?
2. Duke Nukem
3. ?
4. ?
5. System Shock 2
6. Half Life/Half Life 2
7. Deus Ex
8. ?
9. Rage
10. ?
11. DOOM, original flavor
12. ?
13. ?
14. ?
15. Prey
16. Fallout
17. Fallout

Comment: *[Comments Removed]* - This question has a [Meta Discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14876/28182) about it's on-topicness. All interested parties, please weigh in there.

Comment: The Nuka Cola logo is wrong, as is often the case… the real one does not have the curly "C" of the lesser-known Coca Cola brand.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The book titles refer to other games that came out during the 1990's as well as franchises that are owned by Bethesda.

1. **Daikatana** - [Superfly Johnson](https://daikatana.fandom.com/wiki/Superfly_Johnson) is a sidekick to Daikatana's protagonist, Hiro Miyamoto, and accompanies you throughout much of the game. Daikatana was directed by John Romero, one of the major figures in the development of the early id software games including DOOM I & II.
2. **Duke Nukem** - The name "Dork Norkem" is a play on words of Duke Nukem. The unflattering name of the author may refer to the rivalry between id Software and 3D Realms (the developers of Duke Nukem).
3. **Devil Daggers** - [an indie game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_Daggers) insipired by Doom/Quake.
4. **Unreal** - the [Liandri Mining Corporation](https://unreal.fandom.com/wiki/Liandri_Mining_Corporation) is the organiser of the Tournaments in the Unreal setting and acts as an antagonist in many of the games.
5. **System Shock 2** - the [Von Braun](https://shodan.fandom.com/wiki/Von_Braun) is the spaceship in which SS2 is set, and the primary antagonist of the series is the rogue AI [SHODAN](https://shodan.fandom.com/wiki/SHODAN).
6. **Half-Life** - [Unforeseen Consequences](https://combineoverwiki.net/wiki/Unforeseen_Consequences) is the third chapter of the game, the location where these consequences originate is the [Black Mesa Research Facility](https://combineoverwiki.net/wiki/Black_Mesa_Research_Facility).
7. **Deus Ex** - [UNATCO](https://deusex.fandom.com/wiki/United_Nations_Anti-Terrorist_Coalition) (United Nations Anti-Terrorist Coalition) is the agency that the protagonist, JC Denton, initially works for. In dialogue the name is always pronounced "u-nat-co" as a word rather than initialised. The game also has a scene which became [a minor meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/oh-my-god-jc-a-bomb) involving the discovery of a bomb.
8. [**Wolfenstein 3D: Spear of Destiny**](https://wolfenstein.fandom.com/wiki/Wolfenstein_3D:_Spear_of_Destiny) - A prequel to the game Wolfenstein 3D, both of which were developed by Id Software, who also developed the original DOOM.
9. [**Rage**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rage_(video_game)) - A game by id Software in the similar vein to the Fallout series.
10. **Quake series** - [Stroggs](https://quake.fandom.com/wiki/Strogg) are alien invaders that are bad guys in Quake 2 and Quake 4 and are playable characters in multiplayer games (e.g. in Q3 Arena). Their logo is also present in original Quake on so called Strogg Crates.
11. **DOOM**, original flavor - Flynn Taggart is a known alias of the original Doom Guy, primarily in the novelizations of the original games which... deviate from the game canon, to put it mildly, hence the mention of [retconning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroactive_continuity).
12. **Commander Keen** - [Dopefish](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/dopefish) is a large green cartoony fish featured in the game.
13. **DOOM** - [Tei Tenga](https://doom.fandom.com/wiki/Tei_Tenga) is a planet or a moon which is mentioned as off-world mining place in original Doom and in 2016 Doom reboot.
14. **The Ultimate Doom** - [Thy Flesh Consumed](https://doom.fandom.com/wiki/Thy_Flesh_Consumed) is the final episode in the game.
15. **Prey** - The [title here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prey_2) refers to the on/off nature of the cancelled sequel to the original Prey. It might also refer to the minor controvesy about if the 2017 game is a reboot or a sequel.
16. **Fallout** - The protagonists in the Fallout series are called Vault Dwellers, and an item in various Fallout games is the 'Wasteland Survival Guide'. This guide would be useful to them to survive the nuclear wasteland.
17. **Fallout** - Nuka-Cola is a beverage in the Fallout universe.

Comment: Perhaps a candidate for #3 is Diablo. #15 seems to reference Prey (2017) as not a sequel to Prey (2006), and Prey 2 was "in development hell" and then cancelled.

Comment: #7 also has Dota 2 logo

Comment: About #2, I seem to recall that the intro sequence of Duke's second game mentions he's a celebrity and has written a book titled something like "why I'm so great", hence the "part II".

Answer (score 1):

With my copy I don't have number 17, instead of that I have "how to comb your mustache" by Clifton M Fischbach...Is that a reference to Markipler? (Last name Fischbach and known for a character called Wilfred Warfstache with a huge pink mustache)

Please tell me if I am completely wrong.

Comment: [It seems](https://www.reddit.com/r/HalfLife/comments/flp7fu/small_halflife_easter_egg_in_doom_eternal/) you're right. Also, the nick-name of the mother of the 'author' was *Doom* (Flora Marie Doom Fischbach). Maybe you can edit some of the information found in that thread into your answer, including the screenshot of the alternative #17 title?

Comment: [You are not wrong](https://youtu.be/THaQS27IGlI?t=969) - Mark confirmed this in his video of the game.  But, they must have updated the game to change book #17 since the posting of this question, as Mark's video some-what alludes to this by the sounds of it.  They put it in the game as a way of thanking him for playing the game (from what I gather).

Comment: This seems like it's not an answer. It's a question